# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (118 ... 119) ends beyond length 118

Tags: java, android, spannablestring

I searched different questions but found nothing specific about my problem. I am changing text color by selecting color and works successfully however when I start deleting my edit text after typing a color text I get this error.

```
myedittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(txtColor)), start, start+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
```

I get the following error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (118 ... 119) ends beyond length 118
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1309)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:680)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:672)
    at com.apps.primalnotes.Fragments.EditorFragment$16.onTextChanged(EditorFragment.java:842)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:10611)
    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:10715)
    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:14057)
```

I am writing in two colors now like this

[image]

now when i save it. it saves in pink color only and shows me like this
[image]
[image]
but now when i save it again without any changes it save in the colors i wrote it
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The onTextChanged method is invoked to tell you that within `CharSequence s`, number of character `count` beginning at `start` have just replaced old text that had length `before`.

What is happening is that when user presses backspace, start is at the upper limit of your charsequence i.e. If you had seven character before, start is 6 which is the same as the last element. You are doing `start+1` which is always a number out of index range.

```
myedittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(start < s.length() - 1 || count > before){
                spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(txtColor)), start, start+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
```

Didn't get to try that code but it should work. It's just to show you an idea of what you are doing wrong and what you should be doing.

Comment: Hi, so a new problem I am facing here and that is when I try to write text in two colors and then save it then it saves the text in the first color. Let's suppose I try first to write in red and then in blue but it saves only all the text in red. but when I save it again changing then it shows me red and blue color and again on saving without changes it again shows the red color text only.

Comment: Explain properly pls.

Comment: Please look for the images in the question i added with little explaination

Comment: How are you saving? This seems to be another question on its own and you will help more people by asking it as a different question.

Answer (score 3):

When you delete text from the end of the string, the `onTextChanged()` method will be invoked with values representing the fact that the string is now shorter. It looks like you've written your code to always assume that the length will be longer; you're coloring in the just-typed character. But if you delete a character instead, you probably don't want to do this.

You could add a check to make sure that `count` is greater than `before`, this at the very least will indicate that text was added to the string.

```
if (count > before) {
    spannableString.setSpan(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Solved my problem